# XLS: 'if statement' calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice

I have a cell `B19` which consists of taking the value of another cell and dividing it by 5:

```
=B15/5
```

However I'd like to change it so that it only divides it by 5 if the `B15` is more than 1000... and for it to only include how much is *over 1000* in the calculation.

So if B15 was, for example, `1250`... then `B19` should be `50`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
=IF(B15>1000,(B15-1000)/5,B15)
```

- If B15>1000, the difference between B15 and 1000 is divided by 5.
- If not, then the value of B15 is shown. You can adapt this part to suit your needs.